# WPF RotateTransform Angle property binding issue

Tags: wpf

I have a `ListBox.ItemTemplate` defined as

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Border
        x:Name="dotBorder"
        ...
        Cursor="Hand">
        <Grid
            x:Name="dot"
            Height="58"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Tag="{Binding Id}">
            ...
            <Border Grid.Column="3" PreviewMouseDown="Arrow_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                <TextBlock
                    x:Name="arrow"
                    ...>
                    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding IsExpanded, Converter={StaticResource boolToValue}, ConverterParameter=90}" />
                    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

My issue is that the `RotateTransform` doesn't seem to know when `IsExpanded` changes, so the Converter doesn't get triggered. I've tried declaring the binding with RelativeSource, ElementName etc but to no avail. No binding errors are shown. Any ideas?

Later Edit:

Discovered some weird behavior: if I make a small change to the `TextBlock` xaml during runtime (e.g. remove the VerticalAlignment), then everything starts working as expected - the Binding automatically "fixes" itself. It's like the `DataContext` of the `RotateTransform` doesn't get loaded until then.

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't in your `boolToValue` converter? Do any binding errors appear in the XAML Binding Errors window in VS?

Comment: IsExpanded is a property of the data item class, and its setter fires a change notification?

Comment: Side-note: you probably don't need to do this: `Tag="{Binding Id}"` - the `Tag` properties are a legacy of _old-old-school_ WPF, when people were using it like WinForms, with manual event-handlers and excessive amounts of code-behind code, before data-binding was cool and MVVM was tolerable. You also generally don't need to set `x:Name` either.

Comment: I use `x:Name` because I style the listboxitems with DataTriggers that I have not included here. `IsExpanded` is a property on the items in the `ListBox.ItemsSource`, which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so it's not a notification issue. I have no binding errors. The converter itself seems to work fine, I added a breakpoint and it doesn't get hit. I can trigger the converter by hot reloading some XAML change on the TextBlock.

Answer (score 0):

The RendeTransform is an island of encapsulation, so I think you need to do your binding differently - something like:

```
 <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}, Path=DataContext.IsExpanded, Converter={StaticResource boolToValue}, ConverterParameter=90}" />
```

Comment: Already tried this. Unfortunately it doesn't work.